# How do zeroes impact regression estimates?

Tags: regression, estimation

Assume I am estimating a simple cross-sectional regression model. What happens if a large portion of the cross sections consists of zeros only? That is, both the dependent and the independent variables are zero.

Do these cross-sections even have an impact on the estimation at all? Or are they excluded from the estimation.

Comment: Thinking about it myself I guess it depends wether the model includes an intercept or not. If it does, I would assume that the intercept estimate is dragged down to zero. If there is no intercept, zero values would not have an impact at all. But this is just my thought on it...

Comment: If both the dependent and independent variables have a lot of zeros and these are valid data, then a zero value of the independent variable is a pretty good predictor of the dependent variable for those cases.  However we would need to know more about  the rest of your data to say much more.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But in the case of zeroes only, how does this affect the estimated coefficient? Because 0*1 is the same as 0*1000000. In other words, if the dependent variable aswell as the independent variables are zeroes only, the coefficients could take on any value as far as I understand basic algebra. There is no "optimal" value looking at the zeroes solely. Thus, I am left wondering how they effect the global estimate of the regression coefficients.

Comment: We need more info about the data.

Comment: I do not have a specific dataset. I am just hypothetically thinking about the issue. And in my opinion, stating wether such 0 value cross sections have a theoretical impact on the regression estimates or not is not dependent on the rest of the data. It either has an impact in theory or not. I am not interested in the exact influence. I am just interested in wether such cross sections are part of the estimation process or wether they are excluded from it.

Comment: Consider a two-dimensional plane. In $y = \beta_0+\beta_1x$ setting, it is clear that adding more and more points $(0,0)$ will drag the line to pass through origin, making $\beta_0$ closer to zero. Where the line goes (slope, $\beta_1$) is determined by other non- $(0,0)$ points. I don't know if this is what you're looking for, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will definitely have an impact on your model. Here's a simple simulation to demonstrate. Feel free to fiddle with this code on your own.

It will change slope, intercept, and MSE. It could give you the illusion of a better fit because those (0,0) points will have very low residuals. If the center of your data is not (0, 0), then they'll be high-leverage too.

You need to consider the origin of your zeros. Are they true zeros? Or are they censored values? What to do depends on your question of interest.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Specify model parameters
n_nonzero = 20
n_zero = 20

beta0 = 5
beta1 = 0.2

mean_x = 5


# Generate data without zeros
x = rnorm(n_nonzero, mean_x, 1)
y = beta0 + beta1 * x + rnorm(n_nonzero, 0, 1)

dat_no_zeros = data.frame(cbind(y, x))
dat_no_zeros = dat_no_zeros[sample(nrow(dat_no_zeros)),]
# Plot
p_no_zeros = ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y), data=dat_no_zeros) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  ggtitle('Without zeros')

# Add zeros to above data
x2 = c(x, rep(0, n_zero))
y2 = c(y, rep(0, n_zero))

dat_with_zeros = data.frame(cbind(y2, x2))
dat_with_zeros = dat_with_zeros[sample(nrow(dat_with_zeros)),]
# Plot
p_with_zeros = ggplot(aes(x=x2, y=y2), data=dat_with_zeros) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method='lm') +
  ggtitle('With zeros')

grid.arrange(p_no_zeros, p_with_zeros, ncol=2)
```

[image]